# When I tried passing data as a button with intent there is no button that appears?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to have it so that when you click the plus button, you go to a separate page and you can put your question and the answer on that page. When you're done you click the check button and it takes you back to the page where a new button with the text set as the question appears. I coded this and thought I got it down but when I actually tested it, no button was created. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Mainpage:

```
class Newbtn : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newbtn)

        val newbutton = Button(this@Newbtn)
        val btn = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn2)
        val intent2 = Intent(this@Newbtn, QuestionPage::class.java)
        val intent = getIntent()
        val test = intent.getStringExtra("test")

        btn.setOnClickListener{
            newbutton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            newbutton.width=1010
            newbutton.height=300
            newbutton.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            newbutton.translationX= 65F
            newbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"))
            newbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#250A43"))

            startActivity(intent2)
            newbutton.text = test
        }
    }
}
```

Question/answer page:

```
class QuestionPage : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question_page)

        val btn3 = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn3)
        val intent = Intent(this@QuestionPage, Newbtn::class.java)
        val question = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)
        val answer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)
        val questiontext = question.text.toString()
        val answertext = answer.text.toString()

        intent.putExtra("test", questiontext)

        btn3.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Question/answer xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".QuestionPage">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#99141414"
        android:backgroundTint="#180030"
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:hint="type in question"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:translationX="120dp"
        android:translationY="150dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#99141414"
        android:backgroundTint="#180030"
        android:hint="type in answer"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:translationX="-45dp"
        android:translationY="400dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:translationX="-20dp"
        android:translationY="600dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background"
        android:contentDescription="@string/dsfd"
        android:focusable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you start new activity in questionpage,
better to using startActvitityForResult() to open questionpage,
then don't forget to override onActivityResult() in Mainpage to catch intent from questionpage.
in main page :

```
val activityCode = 2
startActivityForResult(
                Intent(this@MainPage, QuestionPage:class.java), activityCode
            )

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
if (requestCode == activityCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
     val buttonText = data?.getStringExtra("test")
   // set your button text here
}
```

in question page :

```
val returnIntent = Intent()
returnIntent.putExtra("test", questiontext)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
            finish()
```

Comment: should this be under the btn.setOnClickListener for the mainpage code?

Comment: I keep getting "modifier override is not applicable to local function" error

Answer (score 0):

I am not Kotlin professional.
I found an issue in your source code which is you didn't implement unit on button's width and height

```
newbutton.width=1010
newbutton.height=300
```